# Two graph is not coming in one row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have tried this code to make two graphs in two columns in one row but it's now showing in two columns.

```html
<div class="tile-stats" style="width: 100%; height: 570px; border:1px solid blue;">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="background-color: white; border:thin; border-color:grey;">
        <div id="vis" class="col-md-8"  style="background-color: white; width:980px; height:570px; margin-left:0px">
            <svg style="margin-bottom:0px;"></svg>
        </div>
        <div id="lollipop" class="col-sm-8 col-md-offset-4 col-md-6 "  style="background-color: white; width:650px; height:570px;">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Below are the two graphs I would like to have in two columns in one row:

1. [Graph 1](https://bl.ocks.org/eesur/8678df74ee7efab6d645de07a79ebcc5)
2. [Graph 2](https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/lollipop_animationStart.html)

Also size should be shown in all the browsers. Your help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: please put your code in JSFiddle. and give link for that.

Comment: @kaushalshah no, the question must contain enough code for us to reproduce the problem without needing anything external, a.k.a. a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I got your point. Thank you  for your Guidance.

Comment: bootstrap's grid splits row into 12 cells, you have `col-md-8`, `col-md-offset-4` and `col-md-6` (8+4+6) > 12. And you also set `width`

Comment: Hi Thanks for looking into it. As you can see I have already given two graph with link which need to associated with the div id vis & lollipop respectively. As java script code is not an issue. I am only struggling to adjust the size of two graph which is not feasible to adjust by class col-sm/md/lg